# Python convert a list of lists into a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, casting, tuples

I'm trying to convert lists of lists into lists of tuples.

My Python 2.6.8 code is:

```
1.    dicts = List of dictionaries all with same set of keys foo and bar
2.    for d in dicts:
3.        for f in d['foo']: # d['foo'] is a list of lists
4.            f.change_some_stuff_inplace(with_some_other_stuff)
5.            f = tuple(f) # this obviously doesn't work - it just converts f locally
6.        for b in d['bar']: # d['bar'] is also a list of lists
7.            b.change_some_stuff_inplace(with_yet_some_other_stuff)
8.            b = tuple(b) # again this doesn't work
```

The lines `5` and `8` don't cast my lists into tuples, is there a way to convert the `f`s and `b`s to tuples in-place?

**ANSWER** - in comments:

One needs to do `d['bar'] = map(tuple, d['bar'])`.

Comment: `d['bar'] = map(tuple, d['bar'])` is probably what you're after

Comment: I am - it worked out perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay then:

```
d['foo'] = map(tuple, d['foo'])
d['bar'] = # etc...
```

If you wanted to make this work for both 2.x and 3.x, then use a list-comp instead:

```
d['foo'] = [tuple(el) for el in d['foo']]
```

And then probably make it a bit more generic:

```
for key in ('foo', 'bar'):
    d[key] = [tuple(el) for el in d[key])
```